# Hive - to_date vs substr while retrieving date from timestamp

Tags: hive

I have a timestamp column with data type string. Format of data is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss".
I have two solutions for retrieving just the date part.

1. to_date(col)
2. substr(col,0,10)

Performance-wise, which one of these is a more better solution for huge data size?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question depends on a lot of things, but in general, looking at the explain plan is a good place to start. In my testing, there doesn't appear to be a difference in the plans.

*NOTE: this was tested in a Cloudera environment on Hive version 1.1.0-cdh5.12.2*

Using TO_DATE():

```
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|                      Explain                       |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| STAGE DEPENDENCIES:                                |
|   Stage-1 is a root stage                          |
|   Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1               |
|                                                    |
| STAGE PLANS:                                       |
|   Stage: Stage-1                                   |
|     Map Reduce                                     |
|       Map Operator Tree:                           |
|           TableScan                                |
|             alias: a                               |
|             Statistics: Num rows: 163043612 Data size: 178714012511 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE |
|             Select Operator                        |
|               expressions: to_date(some_date) (type: string) |
|               outputColumnNames: _col0             |
|               Statistics: Num rows: 163043612 Data size: 178714012511 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE |
|               File Output Operator                 |
|                 compressed: false                  |
|                 Statistics: Num rows: 163043612 Data size: 178714012511 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE |
|                 table:                             |
|                     input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat |
|                     output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat |
|                     serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe |
|                                                    |
|   Stage: Stage-0                                   |
|     Fetch Operator                                 |
|       limit: -1                                    |
|       Processor Tree:                              |
|         ListSink                                   |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Using SUBSTR():

```
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|                      Explain                       |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| STAGE DEPENDENCIES:                                |
|   Stage-1 is a root stage                          |
|   Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-1               |
|                                                    |
| STAGE PLANS:                                       |
|   Stage: Stage-1                                   |
|     Map Reduce                                     |
|       Map Operator Tree:                           |
|           TableScan                                |
|             alias: b                               |
|             Statistics: Num rows: 163043612 Data size: 178714012511 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE |
|             Select Operator                        |
|               expressions: substr(some_date, 1, 10) (type: string) |
|               outputColumnNames: _col0             |
|               Statistics: Num rows: 163043612 Data size: 178714012511 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE |
|               File Output Operator                 |
|                 compressed: false                  |
|                 Statistics: Num rows: 163043612 Data size: 178714012511 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE |
|                 table:                             |
|                     input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat |
|                     output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat |
|                     serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe |
|                                                    |
|   Stage: Stage-0                                   |
|     Fetch Operator                                 |
|       limit: -1                                    |
|       Processor Tree:                              |
|         ListSink                                   |
|                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
```